# Magento check quote has order

Tags: magento

**Question:**

Is there a sure way of checking if a Quote object has a related Order object without loading 
the Order object?

**Research**

I have looked at the following ways, but I am not 100% they will be accurate:

- `is_active`, so when an order is complete this field is set to 0, I am not sure that this is the only time it happens though.
- `reserved_order_id`, the wording seems like it can potentially not fill the reserved order.
- `converted_at` (thanks @Marius), always seems to be `null` for me.
- `subtotal`, this looks interesting, if the quote has a subtotal surely it has been ordered.

I guess I could set a flag and add it to the `convert_quote_to_order` observer, but there must be a simple inbuilt way of doing this, really I don't want the extra overhead of joining the order object onto my collection when I am doing then check.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>Check the field `converted_at` (`$quote->getConvertedAt()`). If it's `null` it means it doesn't have an order. If it has an order this should be the date that the order was created.</strike>
**[Edit]**
Ok. I've checked and I can confirm that `is_active` is a reliable way to check if a quote has an associated order. If the value is `0` the quote has an order.
The flag is set to `0` by the method `Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::_inactivateQuote` and this method is called when placing an order:
`Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitOrder`
`Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitNominalItems`
`Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote::submitAll`.
On the other hand, `reserved_order_id` is not a reliable flag for quotes converted to orders. It can be filled in with a value but the order can be missing. I've had in a couple of occasions to write a module where I've reserved the order id before the order was placed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the `converted_at` field is always `null` for me even with a fully complete order. Are you sure that is not for when an order is converted to a quote?

Comment: @input I'm not 100% sure. I will check and edit (or delete) my answer

Comment: thanks. To note also it could be OneStepCheckout stomping around and breaking all sorts of things, pretty characteristic of it.

Comment: @Marius How can do this in magento2?